# Windows remote desktop session is periodically closed

Tags: windows-xp

I have met error periodically when connecting to a windows XP machine using remote desktop recently. When the error happens, I cannot even ping to that machine and have to wait for quite a while to be able to connect again.

Here is the exact error:

> ```
> Error connecting to existing session for administrator (Id 1)
>
> A device attached to the system is not functioning
>
> A new session will be created.
> ```

Do you have ever met the similar problem? How to solve it?

**UPDATE:**

It seems like a network related problem now. I found when the remote desktop session is closed, I can ping nowhere from that machine, but the http connection is not effected. Any suggestion?

Comment: What is in the event logs?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the system resources to see if it is related to that while you are connected?

Also I have heard of this in the past and people have had to remove the Microsoft licensing information in the registry and recreated it.

Also are there any events in the logs during this time that might be useful for us to see?

Comment: I checked the event log, but not found anything when this problem occurred.

Comment: What graphics card to you have, it could be related to the driver for this: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/143924-45-error-connecting-existing-session-solved

Comment: It's Broadcom netExtreme 47xx controller. I've downloaded the latest driver from official website and installed, but it still fails.

Comment: That is a network controller. I said graphics card, what make an model is it? What SP is your installation and architecture?